# Apache Spark + Ignite Cluster Thin Client

Tags: ignite

I am trying to read and write into the Ignite cluster using apache-spark I am able to do that using JDBC thin client but not native method as mentioned in several spark + ignite examples.

Right now all the spark + ignite examples launch a local ignite cluster but I want my code connecting to already existing cluster as client.

Question:-

**How to pass Ignite connection ip and port (10800)  10800 in example-default.xml ?**

Error:- Right now I get this below error

**TcpDiscoverySpi: Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (will retry to join topology every 2000 ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries): [/3.88.248.113:10800]**

Working (Spark + Ignite using JDBC):-

```
val df = spark.read
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:ignite:thin://3.88.248.113")
.option("fetchsize",100)
//.option("driver", "org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcDriver")
.option("dbtable", "Person").load()

df.printSchema()

df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")

spark.sql("select * from test where id=1").show(10)

spark.sql("select 4,'blah',124232").show(10)

import java.sql.DriverManager
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://3.88.248.113")

import java.util.Properties
val connectionProperties = new Properties()

connectionProperties.put("url", "jdbc:ignite:thin://3.88.248.113")

spark.sql("select 4 as ID,'blah' as STREET,124232 as ZIP").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("jdbc:ignite:thin://3.88.248.113",
  "Person",connectionProperties)

spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:ignite:thin://3.88.248.113")
  .option("fetchsize",100)
  .option("dbtable", "Person").load().show(10,false)
```

Not Working requires a CONFIG file which is example-default.xml:-

```
val igniteDF = spark.read
  .format(FORMAT_IGNITE) //Data source type.
  .option(OPTION_TABLE, "person") //Table to read.
  .option(OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, CONFIG) //Ignite config.
  .load()
  .filter(col("id") >= 2) //Filter clause.
  .filter(col("name") like "%J%") //Another filter clause.
```

Full Code:- (sparkDSLExample) function fails to connect ignite remote cluster using thin

```
package com.ignite.examples.spark

import com.ignite.examples.model.Address
import org.apache.ignite.{Ignite, Ignition}
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.SqlFieldsQuery
import org.apache.ignite.client.{ClientCache, IgniteClient}
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.{CacheConfiguration, ClientConfiguration}
import java.lang.{Long => JLong, String => JString}

import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.SqlFieldsQuery
import org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteDataFrameSettings.{FORMAT_IGNITE, OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, OPTION_TABLE}
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

object SparkClientConnectionTest {

  private val CACHE_NAME = "SparkCache"

  private val CONFIG = "/Users/kalit_000/Downloads/designing-event-driven-applications-apache-kafka-ecosystem/05/demos/kafka-streams-after/ApacheIgnitePoc/src/main/scala/com/ignite/examples/config/example-ignite.xml"

  def setupExampleData = {

    val cfg2 = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("3.88.248.113:10800")
    val igniteClient:IgniteClient = Ignition.startClient(cfg2)

    System.out.format(">>> Created cache [%s].\n", CACHE_NAME)

    val cache:ClientCache[Integer, Address] = igniteClient.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME)

    cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Person"))
      .setSchema("PUBLIC")).getAll

    cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(String.format("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person (id LONG,street varchar, zip VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) WITH \"VALUE_TYPE=%s\"", classOf[Address].getName))
      .setSchema("PUBLIC")).getAll

    cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("INSERT INTO Person(id,street, zip) VALUES(?,?, ?)").setArgs(1L.asInstanceOf[JLong],"Jameco", "04074").setSchema("PUBLIC")).getAll
    cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("INSERT INTO Person(id,street, zip) VALUES(?,?, ?)").setArgs(2L.asInstanceOf[JLong],"Bremar road", "520003").setSchema("PUBLIC")).getAll
    cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("INSERT INTO Person(id,street, zip) VALUES(?,?, ?)").setArgs(3L.asInstanceOf[JLong],"orange road", "1234").setSchema("PUBLIC")).getAll

    System.out.format(">>> Data Inserted into Cache [%s].\n", CACHE_NAME)

    val data=cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from Person").setSchema("PUBLIC")).getAll

    println(data.toString)
  }

  def sparkDSLExample(implicit spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
    println("Querying using Spark DSL.")
    println


    val igniteDF = spark.read
      .format(FORMAT_IGNITE) //Data source type.
      .option(OPTION_TABLE, "person") //Table to read.
      .option(OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, CONFIG) //Ignite config.
      .load()
      .filter(col("id") >= 2) //Filter clause.
      .filter(col("name") like "%J%") //Another filter clause.

    println("Data frame schema:")

    igniteDF.printSchema() //Printing query schema to console.

    println("Data frame content:")

    igniteDF.show() //Printing query results to console.
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    setupExampleData

    //Creating spark session.
    implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Spark Ignite data sources example")
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.executor.instances", "2")
      .getOrCreate()

    // Adjust the logger to exclude the logs of no interest.
    Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("org.apache.ignite").setLevel(Level.INFO)

    //sparkDSLExample


    val df = spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:ignite:thin://3.88.248.113")
    .option("fetchsize",100)
    //.option("driver", "org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcDriver")
    .option("dbtable", "Person").load()

    df.printSchema()

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")

    spark.sql("select * from test where id=1").show(10)

    spark.sql("select 4,'blah',124232").show(10)

    import java.sql.DriverManager
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://3.88.248.113")

    import java.util.Properties
    val connectionProperties = new Properties()

    connectionProperties.put("url", "jdbc:ignite:thin://3.88.248.113")

    spark.sql("select 4 as ID,'blah' as STREET,124232 as ZIP").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("jdbc:ignite:thin://3.88.248.113",
      "Person",connectionProperties)

    spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:ignite:thin://3.88.248.113")
      .option("fetchsize",100)
      .option("dbtable", "Person").load().show(10,false)

  }

}
```

example-default.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<!--
    Ignite configuration with all defaults and enabled p2p deployment and enabled events.
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default is false. -->
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>

        <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
                <!--Task execution events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED"/>

                <!--Cache events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED"/>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>3.88.248.113:10800</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC thin client is the only way to connect Ignite on AWS + Spark from outside ignite cluster which was answered in below grid gain blog.

https://forums.gridgain.com/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=13f5e836-1569-486a-8475-84c70fc141e0&CommunityKey=3b551477-7e2d-462f-bc5f-d6d10ccbbe35&tab=digestviewer&SuccessMsg=Thank+you+for+submitting+your+message.

Spark + Ignite Example:-
https://github.com/kali786516/ApacheIgnitePoc/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/ignite/examples/spark/SparkIgniteCleanCode.scala

Answer (score 1):

Like it was answered in http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Apache-Spark-Ignite-Connection-Issue-td29797.html you are trying to connect a thick client to the thin client port.

Comment: sorry I didn't get any answer from the forums, can I get a straight answer I did try ec2 public address and port 47500..47509 in my example-default.xml but still no luck, tried ec2_public_ip:10800 the table created without spark thin client I mean using spark dataframes doesn't exists in ignite .sqline shell I only see tables which are created using spark jdbc thin client

Comment: all the documentation of Ignite doesn't make sense